# maven-war-plugin : exclude many dependencies from lib folder

Tags: java, maven, war, maven-war-plugin

I'm using maven-war-plugin to generate a WAR file.

In the dependency hierarchy, I can see many transitive dependencies, which are extract in the lib folder.

After many research, I saw that the easiest way to exclude them from the war lib folder is to declare them as 'provided' in my dependencies.

However, I have a lot of dependencies to exclude, and I have to do this in many WAR pom file.

My question is :

Is there a way to group all these dependencies in a 'pom' packaging, and use this new artifact in my WAR pom file ?

Comment: Why would you exclude the dependencies in such a wholesale fashion?  If you depend on a library at compile time, then chances are you're going to need that library at runtime.  If that's not the case, then just remove the dependency period

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your needs...

try this--> http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/including-excluding-files-from-war.html

when you build the war you can exclude all dependencies you want in this way:

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
      <!--
        Exclude JCL and LOG4J since all logging should go through SLF4J.
        Note that we're excluding log4j-<version>.jar but keeping
        log4j-over-slf4j-<version>.jar
      -->
      <packagingExcludes>
        WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-*.jar,
        %regex[WEB-INF/lib/log4j-(?!over-slf4j).*.jar]
      </packagingExcludes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Comment: This only excludes JAR files that are in src/main/webapps/WEB-INF/lib, not transitive dependencies which are copied into WEB-INF/lib automatically.